# I want to sum the values stored in two textfiles using binary reader/writer ,but when i run the code it doesnt shows the output ,dont even exceptions

Tags: c#, text-files, read-write

Problem definition of is as following:
  I need to design an application which save numbers to a file. After clicking on Add button, it should perform addition of these stored numbers and display the sum.(Use `TextMode`)...

```
     namespace exam
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\MYPC\Desktop\trial.txt",FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            bw.Write(textBox1.Text);
            bw.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Save to textfilet trial...");
            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\MYPC\Desktop\temp.txt", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter bw1 = new BinaryWriter(fs1);
            bw1.Write(textBox2.Text);
            bw.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Save to textfile.. temp.");



        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\MYPC\Desktop\trial.txt",FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReader bw= new BinaryReader(fs);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {

                byte[]ar=new byte[500];

                while (bw != null)
                {
                    ar[i] = (byte)bw.Read();
                    sum = ar[i] + ar[i + 1];
                }
                textBox3.Text = sum.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: Place a breakpoint, debug your click handler, and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, try something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\MYPC\Desktop\trial.txt", textBox1.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Save to textfilet trial...");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\MYPC\Desktop\temp.txt", textBox2.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Save to textfile.. temp.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LOG>?!
            throw ex;
        }


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int file1IntVal = int.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\MYPC\Desktop\trial.txt"));
            int file2IntVal = int.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\MYPC\Desktop\temp.txt"));
            textBox3.Text = file1IntVal + file2IntVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LOG>?!
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you really want to use the binary reader/writer I suggest you look at the examples in the link below:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_binary_files.htm